# HTTP Get from a C++ server

Tags: c++, http, server, cors, angular-httpclient

I have a client in Angular and my server is in C++. I know it's better to use node but using a C++ server is a restriction. I'm using this [server](https://github.com/LambdaSchool/C-Web-Server/tree/solution) I found on GitHub. When I do a httpClient.get request, it returns an error.

Code in server:

```
int send_response(int fd, char *header, char *content_type, char *body) {
   const int max_response_size = 65536;
   char response[max_response_size];

   // Get current time for the HTTP header
   time_t t1 = time(NULL);
   struct tm *ltime = localtime(&t1);

   // How many bytes in the body
   int content_length = strlen(body);

   int response_length = sprintf(response,
       "%s\r\n"
       "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: %s\r\n"
       "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: %s\r\n"
       "Content-Length: %d\r\n"
       "Content-Type: %s\r\n"
       "Date: %s" // asctime adds its own newline
       "Connection: close\r\n"
       "\r\n" // End of HTTP header
       "%s",

       header,
       "*",
       "POST, GET",
       content_length,
       content_type,
       asctime(ltime),
       body
    );

   // Send it all!
   int rv = send(fd, response, response_length, 0);

  if (rv < 0) 
      perror("send");

   return rv;
}

void get_d20(int fd) {
    char response_body[8];
    sprintf(response_body, "%d", 5);

    send_response(fd, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK", "text/plain", response_body);
}
```

And this is my client code:

```
public my_function(): void {
   let theResp;
   this.getServer().subscribe((resp) => {
       theResp = resp;
   });
   console.log('Return of get: ' + theResp);
}

public getServer(): Observable<any> {
   const httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': '*'
    })
   }
   return this.httpClient.get('http://SERVER_IP_ADRESS:3490/d20', httpOptions);
}
```

Every time I try it I get the same error:

```
zone.js:2969 OPTIONS http://SERVER_IP_ADRESS:3490/d20 0 ()
core.js:1601 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: null, ok: false, …}
```

I know that this is a CORS issue but I can't find any solution. What can I do to reach my HTTP get request and receive an answer?

Comment: As you correctly deduced this has to do with CORS. You have to correctly implement the OPTIONS method which is sent by compliant clients before making a cross-side request or use a client that doesn't send one.

Comment: How can I implement the OPTIONS method? What should the server send back?

Comment: You'll have to refer to your favorite RFC on that point. In practice c++ is a pretty awful language to create a self hosted web server and it's generally much. much easier to simply call the c++ code from a web server in another language.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) requires `\r\n` and not `\n`.

Comment: I added `\r\n` like in the edit but it did not work. I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk, to easily create a c++ server.

Regarding the code you are using, you probably need to modify the function

```
void handle_http_request(int fd)
```

To deal with the OPTIONS verb something probably like

```
else if (strcmp(request_type, "OPTIONS") == 0) {
    if (strcmp(request_path, "/d20") == 0) {
          options_d20(fd, body);

        } else {
          resp_404(fd, request_path);
    }
}
```

And then implement the new options_d20 function that would probably require that you add to the headers buffer, these headers:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*"

"Access-Control-Allow-Methods":"GET, OPTIONS"

"Access-Control-Max-Age":"3600"

"Access-Control-Allow-Headers":"Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Authorization, X-Requested-With"
```

But I'm just guessing.